# Error using StatusBarManagerService - java.lang.SecurityException on android.permission.STATUS_BAR_SERVICE

Tags: java, android, reflection, permissions

I wanted to use the StatusBarManagerService, but it's not available on the SDK, so I tried "cheating", using reflection to access it.

I was able to access it, but now it's giving me an error when accessing one of its methods:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: StatusBarManagerService: Neither user 10139 nor current process has android.permission.STATUS_BAR_SERVICE.
```

Is it possible to be granted this permission, or is it simply not possible?

This is my code:

```
    try {
        Class serviceManagerClass = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager");
        Method getService = serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);
        IBinder retbinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(serviceManagerClass, "statusbar");
        Class statusBarClass = Class.forName(retbinder.getInterfaceDescriptor());
        Object statusBarObject = statusBarClass.getClasses()[0].getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class).invoke(null, new Object[] { retbinder });
        Method clearAll = statusBarClass.getMethod("onClearAllNotifications");
        clearAll.setAccessible(true);
        clearAll.invoke(statusBarObject);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And this is what I added in the AndroidManifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR_SERVICE" />
```

Is it possible to be granted this permission, or is it simply not possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the platform AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<!-- Allows an application to be the status bar.  Currently used only by SystemUI.apk
@hide -->
<permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR_SERVICE"
    android:label="@string/permlab_statusBarService"
    android:description="@string/permdesc_statusBarService"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Notice the `protectionLevel` attribute, with a value of `signature` this means that only applications signed with the platform signature and thus part of the device's ROM can be granted access to this permission. You cannot obtain this permission from a self-signed application utilizing the SDK.

Comment: No problem. What is actually interesting is that as far as I know the permission that you really want is STATUS_BAR, not STATUS_BAR_SERVICE or EXPAND_STATUS_BAR. STATUS_BAR is a system permission in which your app must hold and be in /system/app to be granted so you're still out of luck.